# Dnn text editor doesn't change form a basic text box to Rich text box

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5

i have an issue regarding to dnn text editor

```
<dnn:texteditor ID="Texteditor1"  runat="server" />
```

[image]
when i change it `mode` from a basic text box to rich text box it doesnt change.

What can be possible solution.Please help.

Comment: Your picture already shows a rich text editor, is that what's loading by default? What happens if you click on "Rich Text Editor" then back to "Basic Text Box," does it switch to a basic editor? What version of DNN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of DNN are you using? If you're using DNN7 you will want to make sure you are using the RadEditor controller, not FCK which it appears to be.

DNN7 doesn't work with the FCK Editor.